# Google Analytics PHP: get all events with specific label since the beginning

Tags: php, google-analytics

I know I can get all events with a specific label in an interval, but I was wondering how can I get all events with that label since the first event occurred. Something to replace `$startDate` with some magic value that means "beginning"

```php
$data = $analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:xxxxxxxxx',
    $startDate, // !!!
    'today',
    'ga:totalEvents',
    [
        'dimensions' => 'ga:eventLabel,ga:date',
        'filters' => "ga:eventLabel=={$this->type}"
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, the only way is to define a much earlier start date. Note: depending on the number of sessions in the selected date interval you may incur sampling (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en).

Comment: What do you mean by sampling?

Comment: I updated my answer with documentation link